# How to attach backup in Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly SQL DW)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

While creating **Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly SQL DW)** from Azure portal there is a option to attach backup, but I am confused which backup it is asking for. I created a export of Azure SQL database and it's getting detected while creating SQL database from Azure portal but same is not happening with Azure synapses service. In portal when I click on backup, it's not showing any suggestions as it was showing for SQL database. please let me know which and how to attach backup in Azure synapses from both portal and ARM.

Answer (score 0):

This is because-

1. Azure SQL DB and Synapse Analytics are different services offering different storage solutions.
2. You need to have an existing backup of Azure SQL DW (now Synapse Analytics) to restore it into a new instance via Portal or ARM.

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-active-paused-dw)

Comment: I have gone through that link and created a restore point also but while creating a new synapse service it's not showing anything in search bar after clicking on the backup. it's only showing when you try to restore synapse service.

Comment: @NiteshSingh - You can restore it into a new instance from 'Restore' option of the existing service. You do not have to create a new instance separately and then select the backup. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: i am creating a new pipeline for synapse service, so i want to include every possibility in pipeline with ARM. As of currently i nether have ARM nor can get it from portal which can include backup.